# Python Threading Printing Pauses Other Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding an online terminal game and when I print for my recieve message thread it causes the other thread to pause. I am fairly new to sockets and threading so some code may be written poorly.

My main client thread

```
class Client:
def __init__(self, serverobj):
    self.s = serverobj
    self.gameLoop()
def gameLoop(self):
    while True:

        if event == None:
            cmd = input(">")
            parse(cmd, self.s)
        else:
            print(event)
            res = input()
```

Networking Class

```
class ServerCon:
def __init__(self,ip,port):
    self.ip = ip
    self.port = port
    self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
def joinServer(self):
    self.client.connect((self.ip, self.port))
    self.recvThread = threading.Thread(target=self.recvMSG)
    self.recvThread.start()

def sendMSG(self, msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    self.client.sendall(send_length)
    self.client.sendall(message)
    if self.client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT):
        return
    else:
        print("Error sending MSG")
def recvMSG(self):
    while True:
        data = self.client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
        if not data:
            sys.exit()
        print(data)
```

There is some code not included for parsing commands and starting the application but that is the basis. When the recv thread receives a message it will print it but the input line(>) will not show up and the application will stall.

Comment: Are you sure that the prompt ">" doesn't appear or is it maybe just somewhere between received printed data? Generally the basic input and output is not suitable for multithreading. You may need an advanced UI library like curses or a GUI library like tkinter. These need a lot of care about multithreading, too, but it is possible to create a usable UI with them.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don’t really where it’s lost because the data it recieves gets printed but then the program just stalls. I will look into curses more because I was looking into it before but I was wondering if it was a problem with my code or with the input function. Thanks for the advice!